# How do I pass an array to the the az appservice plan update -add command/parameter?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I don't get it how to pass a `key=value` to the `--add` parameter of the `az appservice plan update --id --add` command.
I'd like to run this azure cli command:

```
az appservice plan update --id $plan --add "perSiteScaling=true"
```

However this throws an error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find 'perSiteScaling=true' in ''. Available options: ['elasticScaleEnabled', 'extendedLocation', 'freeOfferExpirationTime', 'geoRegion', 'hostingEnvironmentProfile', 'hyperV', 'id', 'isSpot', 'isXenon', 'kind', 'kubeEnvironmentProfile', 'location', 'maximumElasticWorkerCount', 'maximumNumberOfWorkers', 'name', 'numberOfSites', 'numberOfWorkers', 'perSiteScaling', 'provisioningState', 'reserved', 'resourceGroup', 'sku', 'spotExpirationTime', 'status', 'subscription', 'tags', 'targetWorkerCount', 'targetWorkerSizeId', 'type', 'workerTierName', 'zoneRedundant']
```

The docs for the command are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-update

The docs state about the optional --add parameter:

```
--add

Add an object to a list of objects by specifying a path and key value pairs. Example: --add property.listProperty <key=value, string or JSON string>.
default value: []
```

Comment: I was looking for this command instead and I've found it: `az appservice plan update --id $plan --set "perSiteScaling=true"`.

I'll leave this open if anyone can figure out how to use the command with the --add parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, according to the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-update-examples) there is no direct parameter existed for scaling up an app service plan. (perSiteScaling).

If you want to enable `persitescaling` for an App Service, use the `—set` parameter rather than the `add` parameter. Because the `—add` parameter is used to modify values as well as increase or decrease `sku` capacities for a specific list of objects.

However, `persitescaling` is a feature that can be enabled or disabled for an app service. As a result, you need to use `—set` for `persitescaling`.

*As you have already tried this workaround, I tried a similar approach, and it worked as shown:*

```bash
az appservice plan update --name MyPlan --resource-group <resourcegroup> --sku P2V2 --set perSiteScaling=true
```

[image]

Having followed the above workaround, I found another concept-based alternative:

*Typically, the only reason for scaling up an app service is to increase the* `number of workers`. *As a result, if you increase it as shown below, you can scale up the app service plan as needed.*

```bash
az appservice plan update --name MyPlan --resource-group <resourcegroup> --sku P2V2 --number-of-workers 3
```

[image]

*In addition to that, I tried to get the exact results using Azure* `PowerShell` *and it worked:*

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroup> -Name "myplan" -PerSiteScaling $true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
az appservice plan update --id $plan --add perSiteScaling true
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?